# Howto Embed , load .swf into Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

How can I load a .swf(flash) file in Pygame?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, Pygame does not have a browser widget that supports playing flash. To get this working, you'll have to embed a window from a web browser that does (i.e. FireFox, IE, Safari, etc).

Alternatively, you can use Python's C/C++ interface integrate the [GNU Gnash](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/) project (an open source flash player) into your program. Unfortunately Gnash only supports up to flash 9, and it may be difficult to make your own Gnash UI widget.